# Setting value of datetime-local from Date

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I would like to set the value of a datetime-local input with the current date and time. Right now I have an ugly solution that involves slicing the first 17 characters. In addition it sets the time in GMT instead of the local time. My code is as follows:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="name" id="1234">

<script type="text/javascript">
  var d = new Date();
  var elem = document.getElementById("1234"); 
  elem.value = d.toISOString().slice(0,16);
</script>
```

I have two problems with this code:

1. Is there a way to convert from a `Date` to a legal value without manually slicing the string?
2. I would like the string to be displayed in the datetime-local as `DD/MM/YYYY, hh:mm` (e.g. `05/11/2015, 14:10` it is `13:10` in GMT but I am in GMT+1 so I want to display `14:10`). What is currently displayed is `05/11/2015, 01:10 PM`. I would like to remove the PM and display in local time.

This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so if I am doing it completely wrong and there is a better way to display datetime pickers in html, I would be happy to hear.

Comment: The spec for input type=datetime-local reads like Browser Devs announced "But dates are hard I don't wanna!" and just dumped the problem on every single JS developer.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `toISOString` function is responsible of converting your local date (`new Date`) into GMT.

If you don't want to use GMT then slice, you need to use the pure Date constructor and all of the getX functions, where X is (days, month, year...)

In addition, you'll need to extend the `Number` object with a function that will help you to return `01` instead of `1` for example, to preserve the `dd/mm/yyyy, hh/mm` format.

Let me call this prototype function `AddZero`

```
      <input type="datetime-local" name="name" id="1234">

     <script type="text/javascript">
       Number.prototype.AddZero= function(b,c){
        var  l= (String(b|| 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
        return l> 0? new Array(l).join(c|| '0')+this : this;
     }//to add zero to less than 10,


       var d = new Date(),
       localDateTime= [(d.getMonth()+1).AddZero(),
                d.getDate().AddZero(),
                d.getFullYear()].join('/') +', ' +
               [d.getHours().AddZero(),
                d.getMinutes().AddZero()].join(':');
       var elem=document.getElementById("1234"); 
       elem.value = localDateTime;
     </script>
```

[See this](https://jsfiddle.net/29fvywtn/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This prints the correct time as a string (05/11/2015, 14:36:30) but doesn't work as a value for a datetime-local

Comment: I am running my code on http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_datetime-local. If you copy paste your code there you will see it doesn't display properly.

Comment: Cool! What do you mean by datetime-local ? Unless I'm wrong, the local datetime is the date and time of your OS, when the runing browser is installed.

Comment: Yeah, when you run your code there it just displays null for me.

Comment: Thanks I will play around with it.

Answer (score 79):

I ended up subtracting `getTimezoneOffset` minutes to adjust the `toISOString` value:

```js
var now = new Date();
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
document.getElementById('dt').value = now.toISOString().slice(0,16);
```

```html
<input id="dt" type="datetime-local" />
```

Comment: I wish there was something more built-in to generate the format needed by a datetime-local input, but this answer works and is simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, the code is clean and easy to ready.

Comment: @Ninja Just like your commenty. XD

Comment: Btw: If your `datetime-local` input has `step="1"` set, and you want the value to not have its second cut out, replace the `.slice(0,16)` part with `.replace(/\.\d\d\dZ/, "")`.

Answer (score 9):

The following function will take a date object (e.g. `new Date()`) and will return a string correctly formatted for `<input type='datetime-local'>`.

```
const dateForDateTimeInputValue = date => new Date(date.getTime() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * -60 * 1000).toISOString().slice(0, 19)
```

Comment: This is not always working because `getTimezoneOffset` it is using `new Date` instead of date.

When date is from before of time switch and we calculate it after time switch offset will be incorrect. Eg. when give time is: `1645100310000`, and current time is `1649067798571`  calling `dateForDateTimeInputValue(new Date(1645100310000))` will give us  `'2022-02-17T14:18:30'` instead of correct one: `'2022-02-17T13:18:30'`

Comment: So the correct solution is: `const dateForDateTimeInputValue = date => new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * -60 * 1000).toISOString().slice(0, 19)`

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution to make it work with timestamps:

```js
  function timestampToDatetimeInputString(timestamp) {
    const date = new Date((timestamp + _getTimeZoneOffsetInMs()));
    // slice(0, 19) includes seconds
    return date.toISOString().slice(0, 19);
  }
  
  function _getTimeZoneOffsetInMs() {
    return new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * -60 * 1000;
  }

  document.getElementById('dt').value = timestampToDatetimeInputString(Date.now());
```

```html
<input id="dt" type="datetime-local" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Since ES6(?) you can use `.valueAsDate` property:

```js
const dateInput = document.querySelector('#date-input')

const localDt =_=>  // return local Date time
  {
  let now = new Date()
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset())
  now.setSeconds(0)       // remove seconds
  now.setMilliseconds(0) // remove milliseconds
  return now
  }
  
// usage :
dateInput.valueAsDate = localDt()  // init date value
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="date-input" >
```

Comment: After clicking `Run code snippet` I got `Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'valueAsDate' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element does not support Date values.`

Comment: @nezu which are your browser and version ?  https://caniuse.com/?search=type%3D%22datetime-local%22 and https://caniuse.com/?search=%20valueAsDate

Comment: Chrome 114. I seems like valueAsDate only works on date inputs in chrome. Tested in firefox and it works there.

Comment: @nezu ... indeed, it no longer works with Chrome... strange, it seems to me that I tested this code on chrome in 2021! it looks like a case of regression. PS: I mainly use FireFoxb (and chromium for some testing)

Answer (score 2):

Leaning on others'...

```
<input id="myDateTime" type="datetime-local">

<script>

    var dateString = "7/15/20 7:9:00 PM"

    if (dateString !== "") {

        var dateVal = new Date(dateString);
        var day = dateVal.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var month = (1 + dateVal.getMonth()).toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var hour = dateVal.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var minute = dateVal.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var sec = dateVal.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var ms = dateVal.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, "0");
        var inputDate = dateVal.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day) + "T" + (hour) + ":" + (minute) + ":" + (sec) + "." + (ms);

        $("#myDateTime").val(inputDate);
    }
</script>
```

The value assigned to the input.val() MUST have every digit placeholder filled in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.mss - see [Proper format for datetime-local value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_datetime-local_value.asp)

Answer (score 1):

as [Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#the_y10k_problem_often_client-side) said there is problem with client side time like this

```js
function setValue(element, date) {
    var isoString = date.toISOString()
    element.value = isoString.substring(0, (isoString.indexOf("T")|0) + 6|0);
}

setValue(document.querySelector("#timelocal"), new Date())
```

```html
<!--midnight of January 1st, 10000: the exact time of Y10K-->
<input type="datetime-local" id="timelocal"/>
```

then you should always add

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
```

when you assign value to this element and minus when u read its value

```js
function setValue(element, date) {
    date = new Date(date.getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)
    var isoString = date.toISOString()
    element.value = isoString.substring(0, (isoString.indexOf("T")|0) + 6|0);
}

var el = document.querySelector("#timelocal");
setValue(el, new Date())

var correctDate =  new Date( el.valueAsNumber + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
console.log(correctDate.toString())
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="timelocal"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, it still doesn't have a native solution to format time elegantly. However, I can compose the format that `datetime-local` wants, `YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM`.

- `YYYY-mm-dd` is the date
- `T` is the seperator of date and time
- `HH:MM` is for the hours and minutes

We convert a Date object and then assign it to the input's value.

```js
const convertToDateTimeLocalString = (date) => {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const hours = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const minutes = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");

  return `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hours}:${minutes}`;
}
const currentTime = new Date()
document.getElementById('1234').value = convertToDateTimeLocalString(currentTime)
```

`toISOString` only shows the UTC time and other `toLocaleString` series methods are difficult and mysterious to be customized so I don't like to use them.

Answer (score 0):

example :

```
 <TextField
   variant="standard"
   style={{width:"50%"}}
 //type='datetime-local'
 type='datetime-local'
 InputLabelProps={{
  shrink: true                                              
  }}
defaultValue={new Date().toISOString().substring(0, (new Date().toISOString().indexOf("T")|0) + 6|0)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill.  If you want only what the OP asked for, jump to the last line, `input.valueAsNumber`...

```
/**
 * Store the given date and time into the given input element.
 * Everything will be displayed in local time, similar to dateAndTime.toString().
 * 
 * Going the other way is easy:  `new Date(input.value)`.
 * @param input This should be set to "datetime-local".
 * @param dateAndTime The date and time to load into the input.
 */
export function loadDateTimeLocal(input : HTMLInputElement, dateAndTime : Date, truncateTo : "minutes" | "seconds" | "milliseconds" = "milliseconds") {
  // The element will remember this value.
  // If you store a time like '2021-12-08T14:23:01.001', the display and the editor will show seconds and milliseconds.
  // If you store a time like '2021-12-08T14:23:01.000' or '2021-12-08T14:23:01', the display and the editor will show seconds but not milliseconds.
  // If you store a time like '2021-12-08T14:23:00.000' or '2021-12-08T14:23', the display and the editor will show neither seconds nor milliseconds.
  // Changing the time using the GUI will not change which fields are displayed.
  // Note:  Rounding or truncating will only remove fields, not add them.
  // If you want to display "14:23:00.000", and you want the user to be able to set the seconds via the GUI, I don't think that's possible.
  // Note:  I didn't see this documented anywhere.  I learned this by experimenting with Chrome.
  let truncateBy : number;
  switch (truncateTo) {
    case "minutes": {
      truncateBy = dateAndTime.getSeconds() * 1000 + dateAndTime.getMilliseconds();
      break;
    }
    case "seconds": {
      truncateBy = dateAndTime.getMilliseconds();
      break;
    }
    case "milliseconds" : {
      truncateBy = 0;
      break;
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error("wtf");
    }
  }
  // This is conversion is surprisingly hard to do.  Advice from MDN and others failed miserably.
  input.valueAsNumber = (+dateAndTime) - (dateAndTime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) - truncateBy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a function to format new Date local time zone into datetime to insert it into mysql registry

```
const dateTime = new Date();
const dateTimeFormat = (dateTime) => {
    
    const localDateTime = dateTime.toLocaleString('en-GB')
    const dateTimeArray = localDateTime.split(',')
    const date = dateTimeArray[0].split('/').reverse().join('-')
    const time = dateTimeArray[1]
    
    return date + ' ' + time
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace this line

```
elem.value = d.toISOString().slice(0,16);
```

with

```
elem.value = d.toLocaleString();
```

This will still print "am/pm" at the end but it takes care of the time adjustment to local values.

Comment: This does not work on an input with type datetime-local

Answer (score -4):

Personally i used :

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="name" id="1234" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');echo 'T';echo date (H);echo ':';echo date(i);?>">
```

Comment: only voting you down since this is in php, OP tags reference html, javascript and datetime object

Comment: I use PHP, also this solution for me works, thx