# DateTime-Locale value isn't being set by javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two `DateTime-Locale` input in a form, and I want to set the values of them to the date and time when the view loads, and 10 minutes after that. I've been following this to do it: [Setting value of datetime-local from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166338/setting-value-of-datetime-local-from-date) , but haven't been working.

These are examples of what I've been trying (in all the cases I've tried with `document.getElementById("eve_start_date_id").value=...` and `var date = document.getElementById("eve_start_date_id"); date.value=...`:

1º, I've tried this one, without the `:ss` and adding `'.Replace(' ', 'T')` to the `ToString`, but this doesn't even execute.

```
function defaultDate() {
    var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    document.getElementById("eve_start_date_id").value = date;
}
```

2º, this function completes, but the value doesn't get assigned. I've tried also with `toLocaleDateString()` and `toISOString()` to no avail:

```
function defaultDate() {

    var d = new Date();
    var elem = document.getElementById("eve_start_date_id");
    elem.value = d.toLocaleString();

}
```

3º, this one also completes but neither assign the value. I've tried this changing the order of `d.getDate()`& `d.getMonth()`, changing the date join from `/`to `-`, the separator of date and time from  to `T`, and adding `:00` at the end of `localDateTime`, to no avail.

```
function defaultDate() {
    Number.prototype.AddZero = function (b, c) {
        var l = (String(b || 10).length - String(this).length) + 1;
        return l > 0 ? new Array(l).join(c || '0') + this : this;
    }//to add zero to less than 10,

    var d = new Date(),
        localDateTime = [d.getDate().AddZero(),
            (d.getMonth() + 1).AddZero(),
        d.getFullYear()].join('/') + ' ' +
            [d.getHours().AddZero(),
                d.getMinutes().AddZero()].join(':');
    document.getElementById("eve_start_date_id").value = localDateTime;
}
```

At this point I don't know what I can try or if I missed some basic stuff to set the value. Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've figured this out. I was using the format that the `DateTime-Local` gave when submitting the form `(dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm)` when the correct format to set the value is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm`, so to make it work, the case 1 should look like this:

```
function defaultDate() {
        var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm");
        document.getElementById("eve_start_date_id").value = date;
}
```

And this is for the case 3, though it's easier using the case 1:

```
function defaultDate() {
    Number.prototype.AddZero = function (b, c) {
        var l = (String(b || 10).length - String(this).length) + 1;
        return l > 0 ? new Array(l).join(c || '0') + this : this;
    }//to add zero to less than 10,

    var d = new Date(),
        localDateTime = [d.getFullYear(),
            (d.getMonth() + 1).AddZero(),
            d.getDate().AddZero()].join('-') + 'T' +
            [d.getHours().AddZero(),
                d.getMinutes().AddZero()].join(':');
    document.getElementById("eve_start_date_id").value = localDateTime;
}
```