# Set input type of datetime-local programmatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form input field `type=datetime-local`. I would like to set it to a certain time and have the actual field update to reflect that time.

I have tried:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-input">
```

I have tried to set it using the following to test:

```
document.querySelector(".form-input").value = "1955-05-24T12:15";
```

I get no errors but the field does not show this date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166338/setting-value-of-datetime-local-from-date refers. seems to be month first? maybe....

Comment: @GavinSimpson in American time zone, however I am in the UK and it asking for the format I put in.

Comment: I just added your code in the project I am currently working on to test, and it worked with no problems. (South Africa here.) Just make sure the javascript is being called after .form-input is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked for me. Make sure the js code run after  element created.